# how to label only number using vbscript in arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, vbscript, maplex

I have a GPS station feature dataset and I need to label using field NAME. However, I need to label only the number, for example in the field NAME the name are GPS123, STATION 239, STN 325 but the label need only appear 123,239 and 325. I already tried using this VB script expression but its not work properly.

```vb
Function FindLabel ([NAME])
  FindLabel = [NAME]
  FindLabel=mid(FindLabel,4)
End Function
```

Comment: Is it always three digits, and always last in your string? If so, you can use that as base to split the string and/or only display those three characters.

Comment: hi martin..  no, some data are 2 digits and some are 4 digits, and the number always last in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a regular expression. The current logic below assumes the format is as described above, i.e. 1 or more numbers in a single group at the end of the string. So it will not find numbers embedded in the string "bob123gps456".

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [FeatureClassName]  )
  dim s, reg, mc
  s =  [FeatureClassName]
  set reg = new RegExp
  reg.IgnoreCase =True
  reg.Global = False
  reg.Pattern = "\d+$"
  set  mc = reg.Execute(s)
  if mc.count = 0 then
    FindLabel = "no number"
  else
    findLabel = mc.Item(0)
  end if
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Hornbydd... i already try it and its work...tq so much..